# How to implement Micro Types using Type Qualifiers and Checker Framework?

Tags: java, checker-framework

I'm quite a newbie in Checker Framework, so I might be doing something completely wrong.

I'd like to get rid of micro-types in our model, so instead of writing

```
private TypeAId id;
```

I would like to write something like

```
private @TypeAId String id;
```

since all of the keys are strings or can be represented as strings.

What is the proper way of doing this? I'm reading documentation about qualifier hierarchy and boundaries but all that seems to over-complicated and I just don't get the basics.

What I want is to have simple annotations like @TypeAId, @TypeBId and etc. so code below should produce compile time errors:

```
@TypeAId String aId;
@TypeBId String bId = "B_ID";
String justString = "JUST_A_STRING";

aId = bId; // Fail
aId = justString; // Fail
```

**UPDATE 1**:
Looks like I need to use "Subtyping", but I don't understand how to write subtype annotations, so following will apply:

```
@TypeAId String aId;
@TypeBId String bId = "B_ID";
String justString = "JUST_A_STRING";

aId = bId; // Fail
aId = justString; // Fail
justString = aId; // Pass, because @TypeAId is a "subtype" of String
```

**UPDATE 2**:
At the moment I have:

```
@DefaultQualifierInHierarchy
@SubtypeOf({})
@ImplicitFor(literals = {LiteralKind.NULL, LiteralKind.STRING})
@DefaultFor({TypeUseLocation.LOWER_BOUND})
@Target({ElementType.TYPE_USE, ElementType.TYPE_PARAMETER})
public @interface ObjectId {
}

@SubtypeOf({ObjectId.class})
@Target({ElementType.TYPE_USE, ElementType.TYPE_PARAMETER})
public @interface TypeA {
}

@SubtypeOf({ObjectId.class})
@Target({ElementType.TYPE_USE, ElementType.TYPE_PARAMETER})
public @interface TypeB {
}

private Map<@TypeA String, SomeObject> someObjects;
```

And get:

```
error: [type.argument.type.incompatible] incompatible types in type argument.
private Map<@TypeA String, SomeObject> someObjects;
            ^
found   : @TypeA String
required: [extends @ObjectId Object super @ObjectId  null]
```

Comment: Does the chapter about the [Fake Enum Checker](https://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#fenum-checker) help?  It contains examples of how to define annotations.

Comment: @mernst, thanks! That's probably what I need actually, I'll give it a try.

Comment: However after closer look it's probably not what I need - Fenum has a little bit different semantics: I can't use it in Map for example:
error: [type.argument.type.incompatible] incompatible types in type argument:
    ```private final Map<@TypeA String, SomeObject> map;```
    ```found   : @TypeA String```
    ```required: @FenumUnqualified Object```

Comment: Good point.  That problem is because of the use of the generic `@FenumUnqualified` annotation, which might be used by arbitrary future type systems.  (It's worth a bug report to the Checker Framework developers, nonetheless.)  If you create a full type system, as described in the chapter [How to create a new checker](https://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#writing-a-checker), you won't have that problem but you will have to write a bit of boilerplate that the Fake Enum Checker would otherwise have handled.

Comment: Regarding your update:  You can specify a subtyping relationship between type qualifiers using the [`@SubtypeOf`](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/api/org/checkerframework/framework/qual/SubtypeOf.html) meta-annotation.  Section [Subtyping Checker example](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#subtyping-example) contains a complete, concrete example of how to create a type system that builds on the Subtyping Checker.

Comment: @mernst, I added Update 2: I created one base ObjectId, which should be default type when I don't specify anything(I guess), also I defined two sub-types TypeA and TypeB.
When I try to use them I get error in the most unexpected place - in Map definition.

In the real code I would have some kind of multimap - Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, SomeObject>>>

That's why I'd like to introduce concept of microtypes or something similar here - it's just to easy to confuse which String is what.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123927/discussion-between-andrei-urvantcev-and-mernst).

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying to do this. I tend to move in the other direction, defining enums rather than annotating Strings. That's the language's solution to the problem you're trying to solve. It has the advantage of type safety, so the checks are built into the compiler.